# How to convert the jquery drag and drop function into angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to create two div. 
In one div there will be 
duplicate items for drag which should not delete after drag.
 In another div drop should happen in which take the copy of items from one div and 
drop to this div with perfect position placing.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Counter
        counter = 0;
        //Make element draggable
        $(".drag").draggable({
            helper:'clone',
            containment: 'frame',

            //When first dragged
            stop:function(ev, ui) {
             var pos=$(ui.helper).offset();
             objName = "#clonediv"+counter
             $(objName).css({"left":pos.left,"top":pos.top});
             $(objName).removeClass("drag");


                //When an existiung object is dragged
                $(objName).draggable({
                 containment: 'parent',
                    stop:function(ev, ui) {
                     var pos=$(ui.helper).offset();
                     console.log($(this).attr("id"));
      console.log(pos.left)
                        console.log(pos.top)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //Make element droppable
        $("#frame").droppable({
   drop: function(ev, ui) {
    if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1){
     counter++;
     var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
     element.addClass("tempclass");
     $(this).append(element);
     $(".tempclass").attr("id","clonediv"+counter);
     $("#clonediv"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");

     //Get the dynamically item id
     draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
     itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
     console.log(itemDragged)

     $("#clonediv"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
    }
         }
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
   text-align: center;
}
#wrapper {
   text-align: left;
   width: 720px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

#options{
 width: 200px;
 height:550px;
 border:1px solid black;
 float:left;
}

#frame{
 width:513px;
 height:550px;
 //background-image: url("../images/UK-Map.gif");
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
     background-position: 0 0;
     border:1px solid black;
     float:right;
}

#tbldevs{
 border:1px solid black;
 width:80%;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-top:10px;
}

#tbldevs th{
 text-align:center;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
}

#tbldevs td{
 height:50px;
}


#drag1 {
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-metallic-orbs-icons-business/078921-blue-metallic-orb-icon-business-tools1.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

#drag2 {
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-metallic-orbs-icons-business/078902-blue-metallic-orb-icon-business-tool-hammer4-sc44.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

#drag3 {
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.com/images/FOwebsite_SinglePreview.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

#drag4 {
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-glossy-pink-orbs-icons-business/107373-3d-glossy-pink-orb-icon-business-tool-screwdriver.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

#drag5 {
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.com/images/ClearCons1_SinglePreview.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

#drag6 {
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:15px;
 background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.com/images/FOwebsite_SinglePreview.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.ui-draggable-helperMoving {
 border: 1px dotted #000;
 padding: 6px;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}

.ui-draggable-helperStoped {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 width:5px;
 height:5px;
}



/* classes for dragged stuff */
.dragged1 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-metallic-orbs-icons-business/078921-blue-metallic-orb-icon-business-tools1.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged2 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-metallic-orbs-icons-business/078902-blue-metallic-orb-icon-business-tool-hammer4-sc44.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged3 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.com/images/FOwebsite_SinglePreview.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged4 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-glossy-pink-orbs-icons-business/107373-3d-glossy-pink-orb-icon-business-tool-screwdriver.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged5 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.com/images/ClearCons1_SinglePreview.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged6 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.com/images/FOwebsite_SinglePreview.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}


#element{
 border:1px solid red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />

    <title>Where have I been? - Demo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Where have I been?" />

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
 </script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css" media="all" />




</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="options">
  <div id="drag1" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag1 -->
  <div id="drag2" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag2 -->
  <div id="drag3" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag3 -->
  <div id="drag4" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag4 -->
  <div id="drag5" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag5 -->
  <div id="drag6" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag6 -->
 </div><!-- end of options -->
 <div id="frame">
  <span id="title"><h2>What do you know?</h2></span>
  <table id="tbldevs" border="1">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>
      <span id="names">John</span>
     </th>
     <th>
      <span id="names">Paul</span>
     </th>
     <th>
      <span id="names">George</span>
     </th>
     <th>
      <span id="names">Ringo</span>
     </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>

   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div><!-- end of frame -->
</div><!-- end of wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using one of these: [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) or [AngularJS + JQuery UI Drag & Drop gist](https://gist.github.com/codef0rmer/3975207)? Maybe they'll serve your needs well.

Comment: I have tried but my requirement is different.I want to drag and drop between two <div>, i have set of elements in one <div> and want to drag the single element from set of element to another <div>.